# Live update (the database & Map) possible in ArcGIS Server 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, arcgis-desktop

I am using SQL Server server database contains lat/lon values and using this information I have created the shapefiles and published on server...

When I get the update say 100 records then I need to recreate the shapefile and merge it to (previous one) like this I am doing daily for last few days...

It is difficult to do daily for all records...

So is there any workaround?? I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 and ArcGIS Server 10.1+ MS sql database 2008 r2

Any help will be great!

Comment: Why create a shapefile? - why not pull the data directly from MS SQL 2008? Do you have ArcSDE?

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks for your reply.. I dont have ArcSDE..I am using 10.1 version for Desktop & Server

Comment: are your lat/lon values in SQL server in a geography or geometry column?

Comment: @Krik Kuykendall.. We are using Geography column.

Comment: @Krik thanks...so Today I got 500 records and I have updated the database similarly its showing in ArcMap 10.1 but not in REST Service.. (After that I overwrite previous map service  and then its displaying the records) So do I need to overwrite service every time ?? why its not updating the records automatically in ArcGIS Server ??..Currently I am going through 10.1 web help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have ArcSDE then you can try the ODBC (Open Database Connectivity)

[image]

Important part:

Goto Start -> and in the search bar type ODBC. right and click on "**Use as Administrator"**.

http://www.code2learn.com/2011/07/microsoft-sql-server-2008-connection.html

Comment: thanks for your reply..I will try it and let you know.. thanks once again..

Comment: thanks for your idea.. I have tried and it worked successfully.. thanks : )