# Access database in Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, ms-access

I am trying to work in Pro on an mxd that was started by a previous employee, and it opens, but the data path on the access database files is all wonky, and the file doesn't show in Pro.

I attempted to follow the solution suggested on a few sites, i.e. via Microsoft ODBC Administrator, add MS Access (.mdb) to User Data Sources, but am stumped at typing in Data Source Name. I don't know what to put here, and the guide I'm following and that most suggestions link to is no help on this.

I'm not super tech savvy, just know how to make maps, so the solution is probably very simple, I just can't find it.  Also, the other solution of right-clicking Database in the Contents Pane and selecting "New OLE DB Connection"...that is greyed out for me, don't know why.[image]

Comment: Can be any name - MyData was the name here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/40432/276

Comment: Instructions are then to navigate to the specific file, but it is on a server not in the C: drive, and the Drives dropdown doesn't show availability of other drives or the servers my access file is on.

Comment: This might be a red herring but have you got the interoperability extension installed and licensed?

Comment: @Hornbydd how do I check that?

Comment: when you start arcpro go to settings > licensing

Comment: MXD is the project file for ArcMap, not Pro. The 64-bit Microsoft drivers Esri uses for Pro don't support Access. You probably ought to use 32-bit ArcMap to convert the personal geodatabase to file geodatabase, update the layer sources, then save the project and resume working with Pro.